# postgresql: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am defining the connection in one file and trying to access that in another file that time I get this error.

Cannot call method 'query' of undefined

config.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://postgres:*****@localhost:5432/test";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

module.exports = {
C : client.connect()
};
```

db.js:

```
var config = require('../config');
var client = config.C;

var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE items(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR(40) not null, complete BOOLEAN)');
query.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
```

why this is showing an error. How can I define the connection in common and access from other files.

Comment: In config.js, does `client.connect() ` return `client` object ? I think it returns null/void or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

config.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://postgres:****@localhost:5432/test";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
module.exports = client;
```

db.js:

```
var client = require('../config.js');
var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE test1(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR(40) not null, complete BOOLEAN)');
  query.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
```

The client will not have null here. The db will be connected and the table will be created

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue in your **config.js**  file. You are assign `C` to `client.connect()` which return void.

You should define as following

**config.js**

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://postgres:*****@localhost:5432/test";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

module.exports = {
  C : client
};
```

**db.js**

```
var config = require('../config');
var client = config.C;

client.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE items(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, text     VARCHAR(40) not null, complete BOOLEAN)');
    query.on('end', function() { client.end(); }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this also, it returns void only. When I tried this way I get this error:connect is not defined

Comment: The way you are connecting is wrong. Check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Comment: When I tried in a page its working fine but its not working well when I tried in two pages